# How can I change UI language as English

Tags: kiwi-tcms

I install it as docker way
Kiwi TCMS is displayed as local language.

I want to see UI as English.

How can I change it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [KIWI TCMS: How to set up source language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67800019/kiwi-tcms-how-to-set-up-source-language)

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67800019/kiwi-tcms-how-to-set-up-source-language