# Default language English and disable translation mode

Tags: kiwi-tcms

I have two questions about languages in Kiwi TCMS.

How can I set up the default language in Kiwi TCMS? The only language I need is English.

So the best choice for me is to disable the translation option for the entire web. Is it possible to do it?

I'm a little confused in which place I have to configure it. I searched the Internet and found this: remove LocaleMiddleware from your settings - but in which setting can I find this option?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [KIWI TCMS: How to set up source language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67800019/kiwi-tcms-how-to-set-up-source-language)

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for has been suggested by @Prome -> *[KIWI TCMS: How to set up source language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67800019/kiwi-tcms-how-to-set-up-source-language)*

To answer some auxiliary questions:

> disable the translation option for the entire web. Is it possible to do it?

No. Because that would prevent community members who wish to contribute translations from doing so. That's why we don't allow you to disable this functionality.

> The only language I need is English.

That's the default, so I don't see a problem here. What you see in the browser is controlled via your browser settings. If you are seeing another language then adjust your browser to prefer the English language.

> The only language I need is English.

How about any other users you serve? Do you wish to deny them the opportunity to use Kiwi TCMS in their preferred languages if they so desire?  If you serve only yourself, then see above.

Comment: But i didn't find any information about posibility of disabling translation function. So it is not possible to turn it off - ok.

And in this post i read this: remove LocaleMiddleware from your settings - so this can disable language settings taken from browser. Could please help me, if this option is still valid and where can i find this configuration?